# htaccess redirect based on specific keyword

Tags: php

I really need to redirect this below URL based on "index/1992" keyword.

http://www.goldcoasttouristparks.com.au/burleighbeach-parkhome/obookings3/Search/index/1992/1?A=&D=&Ad=Adults&C=Children&I=Infants

to redirect http://www.goldcoasttouristparks.com.au/burleighbeach-parkhome/

Comment: Ok, sounds great, you clearly know what you need to do! I'd say: go!

Comment: why don't you use route filters for that?

Answer (score 0):

Put the below htaccess rule at the below of you .htaccess file if any else create a new .htacees file

```
RewriteRule (index/1992) /burleighbeach-parkhome/ [R,301,L]
```